# How to group data by one property and get a merged array of the other properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

There is CSV data from a MongoDB collection:

```
{code: "CHN", numbers: "1000", name: "A"}
{code: "CHN", numbers: "2000", name: "B"}
{code: "FRA", numbers: "3000", name: "C"}
{code: "FRA", numbers: "4000", name: "D"}
```

On frontend I need to group data by key "code" and get an array like this:

```
  [
   ["CHN", ["1000", "2000"], ["A", "B"]], 
   ["FRA", ["3000", "4000"], ["C", "D"]]
  ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code you're having a problem with, what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. If you're just asking "how do I use MongoDB with Python" that's much too broad. Read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const result = [], hash = {};

for(const {code, numbers, name} of input){
   if(hash[code]){
     hash[code][1].push(numbers);
     hash[code][2].push(name);
   } else {
     result.push(hash[code] = [code, [numbers], [name]]);
  }
}
```